# Moshi 1.11.0 - How to fallback values out of enum as null?

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I am aware of this question: [How to fallback on a enum if values don't match in Moshi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119914/how-to-fallback-on-a-enum-if-values-dont-match-in-moshi)

However, it looks that Moshi in version 1.11.0 does not have `EnumJsonAdapter` class included. (Importing does not work for `package com.squareup.moshi.adapters;`)

How to fallback with `null` when deserialized JSON value does not match the one in the `enum`?

Comment: are you including the artifact ID `moshi-adapters`?

Comment: That was it. Unfortunately, the documentation did not state it explicitly.

Comment: https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/master/adapters#download does state it explicitly.